# Picasa "sync to web" folders losing sync when they are moved

Tags: sync, picasa, picasa-web

I've been using the Picasa "sync to web" feature but recently noticed that several folders, with a lot of synced photos and videos inside them, lost their synced status as soon as I moved them to another location on the disk (not through the Picasa "move folder" command).

These folders now still appear with the green arrow indicating that their contents were uploaded, but they lost the blue sync icon they previously had (and are no longer syncing...).

[image]

If I try to reactivate the "sync to web" option for these folders, Picasa starts re-uploading ALL of their contents. This is absurd.. and would take ages to complete.

Is there any way I can somehow get Picasa to recognize these moved folders as the counterpart folder of an existing online folder for sync purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably a bug in Picasa, that was fixed in the version released a couple days ago.

After updating, the folders still lose their sync status when moved, but by simply re-enabling the "sync to web" they almost instantly re-sync, and don't have to get re-uploaded in full as before.

Answer (score 0):

I met with exactly the same problem just as you years ago when I use Picasa.

My solution was to move the folder back to the original location and Picasa will recognize them again. Moving it to the place you want inside Picasa then.

I am not sure whether Picasa changed its behavior on recognizing Photos...